# Grails GORM, eager fetch mode for multiple layers of domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.1

I have the following domain structure :

```
class Survey {

    Integer id
    String title

    static hasMany = [questions: Question]
    static constraints = {
        id()
        title()
        questions()
    }

    String toString(){
        return title
    }
}

class Question {

    Integer id
    String text

    static hasMany = [responses: Response]
    static fetchMode = [responses: 'eager']

    static constraints = {
        id()
        text()
        responses()
    }

    String toString(){
        return text
    }
}

class Response {

    Integer id
    String text
    Integer numberOfPeopleSelected = 0

    static constraints = {
        id()
        text()
        numberOfPeopleSelected()
    }

    String toString(){
        return text
    }
}
```

I've modified `Bootstrap.groovy` to initialise some data on startup, and separate calls to `Survey.list()`, `Question.list()` and `Response.list()` show that each individual level is created with expected values

However, when I do `Survey.list()` and drill into the questions, the responses are always null, like so :

[image]

I was expecting that by setting the [fetchMode](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/fetchMode.html) to eager it should always load that particular object.

What can I change on my domain objects to ensure that when I do something like `Survey.findById(1)` it loads all the questions and responses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please define this in your Survey class

```
static fetchMode = [questions: 'eager']
```

if this don't work as fetchMode 'eager' is deprecated

you can also try

```
static mapping = {
 questions fetch :'join'
}
```

follow this to know more on fetch strategy  https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html